# Variable not found when pasting

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

My code is supposed to export a picture, ranges and text boxes from Excel to PowerPoint. I am getting an error though where it's supposed to paste the ranges as bitmap. The error states that a variable is not found. I am new to VBA and needs some assistance if possible.

Here is the code I am using:

````
Option Explicit

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Sub copy_to_ppt()

Dim wsname As String
Dim Shapes  As Shape
Dim Range As Range
Dim a, b As Integer

    Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPApp.Visible = True

    Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\gdjwherr\Desktop\Brazil Reports\TRP     File\TRP Test Template.pptx")

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    '-----------------------------

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Select
    Selection.Copy

            Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
            (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
            PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
            PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteJPG).Select

            PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top =    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top + 60
            PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left = PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left + 20

ActiveSheet.Range("D3:E8").Select
Selection.Copy

        Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
        (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
        Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteBitmap ```This is where the error occurs stating variable not defined and highlights wdPasteBitmap

        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top = PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top + 60
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left = PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left + 0

    ActiveSheet.Range("G3:H8").Select
    Selection.Copy

            Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
            (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
            PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
            Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteBitmap

            PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top =    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top + 60
            PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left = PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Left - 20


            Set PPSlide = Nothing
            Set PPPres = Nothing
            Set PPApp = Nothing

End Sub
````

Comment: Can you post the exact error message along with any stack traces?

Comment: `wdPasteBitmap` looks like a Word VBA constant - that's not going to be available in Excel VBA. You probably want `ppPasteBitmap`

Comment: @Tim Williams OK changed to `ppPasteBitmap` and now I get a Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error???

Comment: @MrD It was Compile Error Variable not defined and now its the error posted above...

Comment: Where are you tryin to paste to? `Selection` on that line refers to `ActiveSheet.Range("D3:E8")` - did you mean to paste into PPT?  Why are you using a different approach from the first paste operation?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes I wanted to paste into PPT, don't really know why I tried to use a different approach, but this is my new line `PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteBitmap` and its working fine Only now it pastes the Picture to the left of the slide in the middle and the two tables on top of each other... I don't understand why if I'm setting them apart in the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of refactoring...

```
Sub copy_to_ppt()

    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim wsname As String
    'Dim Shapes  As Shape 'don't do this!
    'Dim Range As Range 'don't do this!
    Dim a, b As Integer
    Dim oLayout

    Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPApp.Visible = True

    Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\gdjwherr\Desktop\Brazil Reports\TRP     File\TRP Test Template.pptx")
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
    Set ppSlide = PPPres.Slides _
        (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture 1").Copy
    PP_Paste ppSlide, ppPasteJPG, 100, 100

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:E8").Copy
    PP_Paste ppSlide, ppPasteBitmap, 100, 300

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3:H8").Copy
    PP_Paste ppSlide, ppPasteBitmap, 100, 500

    Set ppSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set PPApp = Nothing

End Sub

Sub PP_Paste(ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide, fmt, posTop, posLeft)
    With ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(fmt)
        .Top = posTop
        .Left = posLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works pretty good just need to add some things here and there to get the text boxes over as well... Thank You

Comment: How would I add the file I need excel to open instead of a new one presentation I would like to add the one I have already?

Comment: Use the same code you had in your original question. I ran a new presentation because it was quicker for me to test...  See my edit.